# AWS VPN Client Endpoint DNS resolution timeout with openVPN

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, amazon-vpc, openvpn

I'm trying to create a AWS Client VPN endpoint. I followed [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/accessing-an-amazon-rds-instance-remotely-using-aws-client-vpn/) AWS tutorial and I always get a timeout error like this:

`DNS resolution error: 30 times.`

I'm not sure what to do, I saw some videos on this topic and it seems I did everything correctly, does anyone know how to debug this? (or what could be the cause)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is really stupid. I tried to check IPs for my endpoint

```
host *.cvpn-endpoint-XXXX.prod.clientvpn.[region].amazonaws.com
```

and

```
host cvpn-endpoint-02aa72c3aa8d442d6.prod.clientvpn.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
```

and both failed. As described in [this](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=295530#jive-message-889096) response, you need to add a random subdomain. By adding this on the .ovpn file (on the `remote` parameter), it works!

Comment: It looks me 1 hour to try to find what's wrong with my configuration until I found this topic. I cannot believe AWS lets us download the .ovpn file and leave this stupid thing for us. Yeah, basically we have to open the .ovpn file with an editor and insert "random." between "remote ".cvpn-endpoint" -> "remote random.cvpn-endpoint.."

Comment: It's not that stupid, here's Amazon's explanation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-admin/troubleshooting.html#resolve-host-name